# What’s wrong with “… enforce that …”

Tags: word-choice, differences, grammaticality, verbs

The following sentence seems grammatically incorrect to me as a native English speaker (should be *ensure*, not *enforce*):

> People then create laws to enforce that these regulations are being followed.

That said, I can’t quite figure out what is wrong with it. *Ensure* and *enforce* are both verbs, and are often grammatically interchangeable with one another.

1. Is there something grammatically wrong with the given sentence, or is it just a strange wording?
2. What exactly is wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ensure* and *enforce* are indeed similar in that they are both [transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb) (i.e. they take a [direct object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28grammar%29)), but not all transitive verbs are equal.  *Enforce* only takes a noun or [noun phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase) (such as *the rules*) as its direct object, while *ensure* is more versatile (from a grammatical standpoint): while it can take a noun or noun phrase, it can also take a [content clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause) (also called *[complement clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28linguistics%29#Complement_clauses)* or *that-clause*; such as *that the rules are followed*) as its object.  This has been established by usage and convention, and it is rare to see *enforce* [paired with *that*](https://www.google.com/webhp?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS475US475&sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#q=%22enforce%20that%22&hl=en&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS475US475&prmd=imvnsfd&ei=YJ5sT6X3C-WW0QHCmIWwBg&start=250&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=144acd61eed23f45&ix=seb&ion=1&biw=1366&bih=643).  In this case, convention dictates the grammatical constraints, and therefore it is grammatically incorrect to use a that-clause as the object of certain verbs (such as *enforce*). [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=enforce,enforce%20that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows relative usages:

[image]

[image]

As you mention, you could replace *enforce* with *ensure*:

> People then create laws to ensure that these regulations are being followed.

Or, if you want to keep the strength of *enforce*, you would need to change the direct object from a content clause to a noun phrase:

> People then create laws to enforce these regulations.

Comment: So this answers my first question (it's definitely wrong, or at least, extremely unconventional). But _why_ is it wrong? What grammatical constraints are violated? Or is convention alone considered sufficient?

Comment: @JohnDoucette If it were conventional to use *enforce that*, it would be correct, and would sound fine to you. But it isn't conventional, and that is what defines the language. Convention is eminently acceptable as a reason for choosing one usage over another.  It's like asking why *prevent that crimes are being committed* is incorrect.  Grammar per se isn't violated, but since the usage has never been preferred, it has become questionable to the point of sounding wrong.

Comment: The reason why it's wrong is that _enforce_ does not govern a [tensed object complement clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/complmnt.html). That means its direct object has to be a real noun or noun phrase like _the law_ or _the deportation order from the judge_, but it can't be a _that_-clause like _that they're being followed._ This is a fact about the verb _enforce_; every verb has its own pattern of prohibitions, affordances, and requirements like these. It's part of what the verb means.

Comment: @John Lawler, would that you made your comment an answer of its own, and it would be the finest answer here.

Comment: Creating laws can neither enforce, nor ensure that something does or does not happen for the simple reason that laws can be broken.

Comment: @Brad: If by *ensure* you mean *engineer it to be 100% failsafe*, what you say is true (albeit tangential).  However, in our imperfect world, we sometimes settle for less in our definitions.  By your logic, nothing can be "ensured" or "enforced".

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the fine answers already given here that focus on grammaticality, it bears noting that laws cannot *enforce* anything- they can merely *prescribe* and *proscribe*, but not *enforce.*
In fact they themselves ***require*** enforcement- thus the existence of "*law enforcement officers*".

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this sentence in print somewhere? I would guess that someone did a cut and paste editing job.

If you use the word "ensure" the sentence is fine:

*People then create laws to ensure that these regulations are being followed.*

If you want to use the word *enforce*, the sentence would be better as:

*People then create laws to enforce the regulations.*

Comment: I'm grading student essays. The writer is not a native English speaker, so I'm not surprised to see unconventional wordings, but I'm wondering what to tell them in this case. That is, I want to help them learn, but am finding it hard to specify exactly why this is wrong (other than convention).

Comment: I agree with @TimLymington's answer. "Ensure that" is an acceptable construction, "enforce that" is not. Also, I would say that "enforce" has the meaning of "compel obedience to," so adding something like "that these regulations are being followed" (even if grammatical) would be redundant.

Comment: @John Doucette, I think the most useful lesson for students to learn is that in many cases there is no specifying exactly what is wrong. All you can do is to say: *This is just not how English works* (as John Lawler eloquently points out in another comment). Then make sure they have the knowledge and tools to determine for themselves if any given phrase they have constructed follows the conventions of standard English usage.

Answer (score 1):

I think both sentences are GRAMMATICALLY correct, at least in the sense that all the parts of speech are used in their proper places. The problem is that "enforce that ..." doesn't make sense in context.

Just because two words are both verbs doesn't mean that you can take any sentence that uses one, replace it with the other, and the sentence will still be coherent. Like, "People then create laws to ensure that these regulations are being followed." "ensure" is a transitive verb. "eat" is a transitive verb. But if I replace "ensure" with "eat" the sentence is jibberish.

Comment: I would say that 'enforce' takes only a direct object, so 'enforce that' is in fact ungrammatical. But YMMV.

Comment: @Tim Good point, I can't think of a sentence where "enforce that" would be valid, not off the top of my head anyway. There's probably a grammar rule operating here whose name I am unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does your third sentence mean? *Enforce* and *ensure* are certainly both verbs, but so is *prevent*.  They are not synonyms, so they are not interchangeable in that sense.  *Enforce that* has no logical derivation and does not appear in the dictionaries; but it is comprehensible, so whether it is 'wrong' depends on your definition.

Comment: I think what I want to know is _why_ it has no logical derivation. As to appearing in dictionaries, do combinations of words typically appear there, and would the failure of a combination to appear really indicate that said combination cannot be used?

Comment: @John: 'cannot be used in idiomatic English', because a dictionary is a list of the ways that words are in fact used.

Comment: To clarify: I meant that a dictionary is not an exhaustive list of all valid English 2-grams, instead containing only all valid English words. Consequently, if a pair of words did _not_ appear together in a dictionary, I would not consider this proof that combining them was invalid English.

Comment: @John: One (or both) of us is confused.  A good dictionary will give a list of prepositions with which a verb can be properly used.  English is not a mathematical theorem, nor even a game of wff'n'proof.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Possibly I have never seen a good dictionary (or at least, never looked for associated lists of prepositions). As to the math, since my students are mathematics majors, not withstanding the nature of English, I like to have logical sounding answers for them. :)

Answer (score 0):

Law *enforcement* is the province of the police. Just because a law is enacted (by politicians), doesn't mean it is *enforced*, or even *enforceable* (by the police).

*Ensure* sounds more correct, but, strictly speaking, it isn't. Simply enacting a law doesn't *ensure* (with 100% certainty) that the law will never be broken.

I would plump for:

> 'People then legislate to **decree** that these regulations must be followed.'

Comment: And how is *decree* any better than *ensure*, as far as making certain a law will never be broken?

Comment: Decree means to state that it must be so -- an official order from a legal authority. This is not the same as ensuring it will indeed be so.